# Were animals created by God before the Medieval Ages, or only after the Space Age?

Tags: medieval-engineers

In the area where I decided to build my base, I can only spot Deer.

Where in the world can I find other animals like chickens, cows, pigs, mules, donkeys, horses? Or they were not created by God until the Space Age?

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=400